# Using Generics in DAO Pattern

Tags: java, generics, dao

```
// Domain Class
public class Actor {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date lastUpdate;

    // getters and setters
}



// DAO Interface
public interface IDao<T> {

    void save(T t);

}



// Concrete Class
public class ActorDao implements IDao {

    @Override
    public void save(Actor actor) {
        // Error: The method save(Actor) of type ActorDao must override or implement a supertype method

    }

}
```

Why is the overridden `save()` not accepting `Actor` when `IDao` has the param as `T`?

Comment: It is against strong Java convention to use `I` in interface names. Also, (1) `Date` is obsolete; you want `Instant` instead, and (2) if you can use Spring Data, it will autogenerate the implementations for your DAO interfaces automatically.

Comment: Got `I` from seeing too much C# haha. `Date` is `java.sql.Date`. Can Spring Data be used for a non-web app?

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is even more obsolete; use `java.time` instead. And Spring Data can be used in any application running on a full JVM (not Android, smart card, etc.).

Comment: Will look into that next, thanks! As far as this thread, all good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify what class that T is, like so :

```
public class ActorDao implements IDao<Actor> {
```